# Connect SAS to AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, sas, rhel, amazon-athena

I am trying to establish a connection between SAS & AWS Athena.
I am working on RHEL 6.7, java version is 1.8.0_71.

Could someone advise how to configure that please?

So far, after some reading on ["Accessing Amazon Athena with JDBC"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) , I have tried a 'maybe it will work' naive approach with trying to set a DSN in odbc.ini files (outside of SAS): I have downloaded Athena JDBC jar file and tried configuring connection in a similar way I did it for EMR.

odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC]
# Specify any global ODBC configuration here such as ODBC tracing.

[ODBC Data Sources]

ATHENA=Amazon Athena JDBC Driver

[ATHENA]
Driver=/opt/amazon/hiveodbc/lib/64/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar
HOST=jdbc:awsathena://athena.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443?s3_staging_dir=s3://aws-athena-query-results/sas/
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Amazon Athena JDBC Driver=Installed

[Amazon Athena JDBC Driver]
Description=Amazon Athena JDBC Driver
Driver=/opt/amazon/hiveodbc/lib/64/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar

## The option below is for using unixODBC when compiled with -DSQL_WCHART_CONVERT.
## Execute 'odbc_config --cflags' to determine if you need to uncomment it.
# IconvEncoding=UCS-4LE
```

iODBC throws the following:

```
iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.0709.0909

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): DSN=ATHENA
1: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]/opt/amazon/hiveodbc/lib/64/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar: invalid ELF header (0) SQLSTATE=00000
2: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded (0) SQLSTATE=IM003
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: JDBC != ODBC, so just adding a JDBC driver to an ODBC config is not going to work.

Comment: "AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar: invalid ELF header" - you're using a Java (.jar) file, where a native Linux executable is expected.  I'm guessing you need an ODBC-JDBC bridge driver in between.